# 500 server error while uploading large size image in Android

Tags: android, image, image-uploading, apache-httpclient-4.x, multipart

I am using Multipart approach to upload images to the server inside my application. If I am uploading small size images then its working fine but a soon as I upload large size image(in Mbs) then I am getting "Internal Server Error" (error code - 500). I am not able to understand what is the issue. I am posting my code here,

```
*HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
HttpPost httpPost = new  HttpPost("MY_URL");

 MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create(); 
    builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
File imageFile = new File("/mnt/sdcard/Hiley Duley1.jpg");
Uri uri  = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
InputStream iStream =   getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
byte[] inputData = getBytes(iStream);

builder.addBinaryBody("userfile", Base64.encode(inputData, Base64.DEFAULT));
builder.addTextBody("place_id", "761");
builder.addTextBody("mall_id", "1");
builder.addTextBody("status", "1");
builder.addTextBody("type", "Photo");
builder.addTextBody("filename", "menu.jpg");
builder.addTextBody("filetype", "image/jpeg");
builder.addTextBody("user_id", "1");
builder.addTextBody("auth_id", "1");
httpPost.setEntity(builder.build());
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,
        localContext);
            response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
return getContent(response);
```

Here, I am using MultipartEntityBuilder to upload the image and getting the image from my phone. If the image size is in Kbs then I its working fine but for images having size in Mbs its giving 500 error. Also, I am using AsyncTask for this process.

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution for this?